# jQuery dataTables and JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, datatables

I try to add JQuery DataTable to my JSP page but nothing happens. I ckecked that all files: jquery.dataTables.js, jquery.dataTables.css, jquery.js is found.

Here's my JSP page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="<c:url value="resources/jquery.js"/>"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="resources/jquery.dataTables.css"/>" />

    <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="<c:url value="resources/jquery.dataTables.js"/>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#student").dataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="student">
        <thead>
            <tr><td>Students</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}" varStatus="loopCounter">
                <tr>
                    <td>${loopCounter.count}</td>
                    <td>${student.studentFullName}</td>
                    <td>${student.studentBook}</td>
                    <td>${student.groupStudent.groupStudentNumber}</td>
                    <td>${student.studentEnter}</td>
                    <td>${student.studentOKR}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: did you use your Browser developer console (Firbug on Firebox , Developer tab in Chrome and Safari ) .. it would show you the JS Error

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I use Chrome but I found no errors